# South Auto-migrate Adding Erroneous Unique Constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I've got the following bit of code in one of my models:

```
channel = models.OneToOneField(Channel, related_name='stories', null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
```

See the `unique=False`? Well, when I use south to create an auto migration, it wants to add a unique constraint:

```
./manage.py schemamigration core --auto
 ~ Changed field channel on core.Story
 + Added unique constraint for ['channel'] on core.Story
```

What gives!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Django, not South. Being `unique` is built into the definition of `OneToOneField`. (You can see it in the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1120).)

If `unique` is False then there can be more than one `Story` with the same `Channel`. This is a ManyToOne relationship, so you probably want this to be a `ForeignKey` field instead.

Comment: New problem: I changed the field to ForeignKey and I'm now getting this error from south: `The field 'Story.channel' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL`. Why would it say this if I have `null=True`?

Comment: My guess is that South is having a problem trying to change the type of the field. As a test, try instead adding a _new_ field with the same parameters and see if there is an error.